# Upgrade wants to install un-needed packages

Tags: package-management

When I run `apt-get upgrade` it includes packages like `firefox-locale-de` even though I removed firefox and have run `apt-get autoremove`.  How can I figure out why my system still wants this package?

Comment: Likely unrelated, but I would personally run `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` instead, since that would install any needed dependencies as well. What packages does it list for upgrade (and only upgrade)?

Comment: @saiarcot895 dist-upgrade gives me the same list of packages.  I just did a fresh install of xubuntu, removed a few things (gimp,firefox,thunderbird) and was hoping an autoremove would remove their footprint, but it isn't working.  I already have firefox-locale-de installed, so it is just an upgrade, but the autoremove should've removed it unless something else is requiring it, and I don't know how to check what is requiring it.

Comment: Also, Thanks for the tip.  I've been running upgrade for years, but looks like I want dist-upgrade as my default!

Comment: What are the exact packages `apt` wants to upgrade (not fresh install, but upgrade)? I don't remember the exact output correctly, but I believe `apt` will give a list of packages it is upgrading, or it might give a list of packages it is installing and another list of packages it is installing and upgrading. Edit your question and add in this info.

Comment: As for dependencies, `apt-cache depends packagename` lists dependencies of `packagename`, while `apt-cache rdepends packagename` lists packages that are dependent on `packagename`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete `firefox-locale-de` by running `sudo apt-get-purge firefox-locale-de`.

If you wish, first run `apt-get-purge -s firefox-locale-de` to give you an idea of what the command will do. Because it is a simulation, nothing will actually be removed and you don't need `sudo`.